# Custom button is not correct size?

Tags: java, jcomponent

First of all, yes, I know I'm a newbie, and this is my first attempt at making a custom Component.

Okay, so in my project, I'm trying to make a custom button that does three things:

1. Draw a background
2. Get the icon of a selected app
3. Draw the app's name in the button.

It can do all three of those, except that the button is *tiny*:

[image: pic]

The icon is the Jar application and the name is "Test Application".

This is the paintComponent(Graphics) method in my class, AppButton:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D antiAlias = (Graphics2D) g;
    antiAlias.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    //g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, arcWidth, arcHeight);
    g.fillRoundRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() - 25, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.red);

    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    int widthOfAppName = metrics.stringWidth(this.appName);
    g.drawString(this.appName, this.getWidth() / 2 - (widthOfAppName / 2), this.getHeight() - 10);

    File refrenceFile = new File(this.appURL);
    try {
        if (refrenceFile.exists()) {
            ShellFolder sf = ShellFolder.getShellFolder(refrenceFile);
            this.appIcon = new ImageIcon(sf.getIcon(true));
            g.drawImage(this.appIcon.getImage(), this.getWidth() / 2 - (this.appIcon.getIconWidth() / 2),
                    this.getHeight() / 2 - (this.appIcon.getIconHeight() / 2), JLaunch.theFrame);
    //Draw the centered Image
        } else {
            ImageIcon noImageFound = getNoImageAvailable();
            //g.drawImage(img, x, y, observer)
            g.drawImage(noImageFound.getImage(), this.getWidth() / 2 - (noImageFound.getIconWidth() / 2),
                    this.getHeight() / 2 - (noImageFound.getIconHeight() / 2), JLaunch.theFrame);
    //Draw the centered Image
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On a side note, if anyone has a good understanding about custom Swing Components, can you also please point me to a good tutorial or a way of learning it like you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one, JButton can draw images. But what you are probably looking for is `JComponent.setPreferedSize()` You can check out the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension).

Comment: Welcome. And you're code is probably better than 75%of the people I go to school with. Carry on!